# Site Collection creation using microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, microsoft-flow, power-automate

Is it possible yet to have a site collection created using Microsoft flow?

I have a list of sites and when a new item is created in that list I would like to have a new site collection created for it. I have it built out in flow but have had no success in the process as of now.

I am wondering if it is even possible?

This is for SharePoint online.

Comment: Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Microsoft-Flow-Provisioning-Office-365-Groups-SharePoint-sites/ba-p/61126) and [this](https://www.cloudsecuritea.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-pnp-site-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-function/) if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Microsoft flow currently has no direct action to create a site collection.

As a workaround, you could use "Send an HTTP Request" action to call SharePoint API to create a site collection.

References:

[Use flow to Create Site Collection](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Create-Site-Collection/td-p/294258)

[How to create a modern team or communication SharePoint site in Power Automate (Microsoft Flow) or Azure Logic Apps](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-modern-sharepoint-site.html)